# Is political correctness applied to science terms something usual in the US?

Tags: united-states, policy

This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master/slave_(technology)) on Master/Slave as defined in technology also include the following:

> In 2003, the County of Los Angeles in California asked that
>   manufacturers, suppliers and contractors stop using "master" and
>   "slave" terminology on products; the county made this request "based
>   on the cultural diversity and sensitivity of Los Angeles County".

To me this looks like [political correctness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_correctness) ("used **to describe language**, policies, or measures that are intended to **avoid offense or disadvantage to members of particular groups in society**") applied to scientific terms.

I am wondering if this is an isolated case or it has become more frequent in the last decades in US.

**Question:** Is political correctness applied to science terms something usual in the US?

**Important note**: **this question is not about whether political correctness should be applied in science or not** (which is very debatable). I am just interested if this is something rather exceptional or not in the US. This is particularly interesting for me, because where I live this is something unheard of (actually most scientific terms are directly borrowed from English).

Comment: I faintly remember something about "Black Holes", but my memory is blurry, and I have no idea whether that was a sensationalized article about an isolated incident or even real at all.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/125524/54237

Comment: Note that while the term "political correctness" has "political" in its name, it's not really a political topic per-se. What terminology to use for what (non-political) concept is a question about sociology, linguistics and academia. I am leaving the question open because it specifically uses a county government as example, but I would like to remind anyone wanting to write an answer to focus on those aspects which actually are relevant to politics and political processes.

Comment: @Philipp - yes, but the County of Los Angeles in California recommending to some private companies to change some labels sounds quite related to politics. The related Academia question is way more interesting, I admit.

Comment: @Philipp This is very 'political'. The problem with likely As is here that the Q is specifically asking "usual thing", ie quantification, not opinion. As without refs that *do* quantify (and probably define/explain beforehand) are automatically partial?

Comment: I wouldn't call them science terms; they are technology terms or computing terms. The county ordinance (or whatever it is) refers to the use by technology companies not by scientists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sometimes happens with hot button topics. See for instance race, where  terms such as "[negro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negro#United_States)" or "[mulatto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulatto#United_States)" went into disuse in scientific publications and public discourse. Or in climate science, where you find terms like climate change, global warming, climate crisis, or global heating -- the [choice of words matters](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2019/may/17/why-the-guardian-is-changing-the-language-it-uses-about-the-environment).

There is also a hilarious episode that involved lawmakers rather than changing public attitudes: the [Indiana Pi Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill). In 1897 the Indiana House of Representives passed a bill written by a crank that effectively set Pi's value to 3.2 and the square root of 2's value to 10/7. (The bill failed in the Senate.)

Not related to political correctness either, but interesting regardless, California's [Proposition 65](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986_California_Proposition_65) might also catch your interest. It requires to warning consumers over the flimsiest cancer risks, and made some headlines a few months ago over [coffee](https://www.latimes.com/business/la-fi-coffee-cancer-warning-20190603-story.html).

Comment: Indiana Pi Bill is a particularly funny and interesting example.

Comment: "Political correctness" is a mischaracterization of the first paragraph. Rather, what you've described there is a situation where terms that were *invented to dehumanize and pathologize* particular groups of people have been largely acknowledged as such, to the point where their continued use is a political statement in support of their original purpose.

Comment: @R..: No quibbles. The nature of "political correctness", in its pejorative connotation brought forward by conservatives anyway, more or less encapsulates what you've written. The link in the first paragraph's last sentence hopefully gets this point across in a more positive manner.

Comment: That 'choice of word matters' as applied to 'climate change' is quite a terrible phenomenon. People need to be educated, start to think about limits of knowledge, epistemology, probabilities, error margins,complexities,  uncertainties etc But Guardian 'style' or 'tips for scientists to communicate effectively to politicians' just acknowledge that almost all people are idiots and still need spoon fed spin to behave right. In the public debate *nobody* talks scientifically, everybody demands a b/w picture to reinforce preconceptions that enable jumps to conclusions to favour their constituency.

Comment: @R.. "Negro" was not invented to dehumanize or pathologize a group any more than "black" was. They are, of course, the same word, and their relative offensiveness has changed over the years. Certainly both have been *used* to do that, but they were not invented to do so--they describe an obviously visible trait.

Comment: The use of racial terms like "negro" and "negroid" has also fallen out of favour among scientists because there is no scientific basis for such racial divisions, which are now considered purely social categorisations (see [this](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Racialism)). Scientific terms fall out of use all the time when they are found not to correspond to reality. Regardless, the question is about computing terminology, not science.

Comment: @StuartF, this is not quite true. Anthropologists _can_ reliably divide people into multiple groups based on their skull features, skin colour, etc. Just like good linguists can sometimes pinpoint your origin down to a village based on your accent. This is all helpful to study human migration and other anthropological things. These groups don't quite align with the "layman" definition of races (e.g: there are quite a few of them in Africa), yet races they are. _Not_ calling them "races" lately is rather an example of PC in science the OP asked about.

Answer (score 5):

Can confirm that the "Master/Slave" terminology (Often used in computing to describe a program that runs as part of the execution of another program) is being replaced for terms that do not invoke slavery (I believe parent/child is more in vogue) and it sometimes requires updating legacy code that relies on the old terminology.

It should be pointed out that L.A. County government can't require a company to make these changes, but the changes from a coding perspective are easy to do and the industry is moving in that direction. The term is largely used in Linux based computing, which is open sourced and very popular in the industry for development environments.  It's hardly any pressure from any government agency at any level.  Los Angeles County weighing in might add more weight as California has a large number of technology companies (L.A. isn't remarkable in the Computer Industry, but Silicon Valley is about 4-6 hours drive, factoring in a specific location and traffic conditions. L.A. County also has a lot of entertainment industry which is very reliant on computing tech.).

Comment: Parent/child describes a different relationship that doesn't imply that one system controls the other systems (because anyone who has ever been either knows that parents do not control their children). The most common replacement I've seen is the objectively terribly hub/worker metaphor, which has no correspondence to the real world, as real workers don't get their instructions from some mystical "hub."

Answer (score 4):

Very much so.  Nature, one of if not the most prestigious general science journals, is currently in the process of changing how they handle race, ethnicity and other socially constructed characteristics.  [They describe the change like this](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-00973-7):

> It is regrettable but true that researchers have used and abused science to justify racist beliefs and practices. As previous editorials have acknowledged, Nature has played its part in perpetuating racism — and has now pledged to play its part in tackling it, together with colleagues in the research community.
>
> As part of this pledge, Nature and the Nature Portfolio journals are updating our advice to authors on reporting research that involves race, ethnicity and other socially constructed characteristics (see go.nature.com/3mtobwx). Specifically, we’re asking that authors exercise care and consideration so that the highest standards of rigour are applied where these attributes are found to be an explanation for an outcome or conclusion. This is part of our ongoing updates to guidance asking authors to describe how demographic characteristics, including sex and gender, are considered in the design of studies — and, more broadly, to consider the research’s potential to cause harm.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes** idiosyncratic usage advocacy, (whether politically correct, scientific, religious, or propagandistic), is not unusual in the US, but **no**, it's rarely applied and most often common sense eventually prevails.

Most such articles boil down to the opinions of some outspoken dissenter, who tends to be articulate but unpopular.  Popular journalism is the cause: journalists need filler stories, and dissenters crave publicity.  Typically such a story about language reform would be reported not because it's important, (*i.e.* the proposed reform is not well-founded and has few adherents), but because it's a [slow news day](https://www.nyfa.edu/student-resources/how-to-deal-with-slow-news-days-weeks-months/).  Language reformers horrify readers in almost the same way stories of murder do, though readers interested in murder write fewer letters to the editor.

Few journalists and editors are honest enough to warn readers in advance that it's a slow news day, and so the public sometimes greatly overrates the importance of filler stories.  Worse, other journalists may uncritically reprint or amplify these stories, so that [a trivial story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junk_food_news) can travel the world over and waste the attention of millions.

Now and then comedians and critics perpetrate benign hoaxes to draw attention to journalistic negligence and inflation, for example:

- [Bathtub Hoax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_hoax)
- [The Society for Indecency to Naked Animals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_for_Indecency_to_Naked_Animals)
- [Fooled by ‘The Onion’: 9 Most Embarrassing Fails](https://www.thedailybeast.com/fooled-by-the-onion-9-most-embarrassing-fails)

Comment: I think that reducing the whole topic to "journalists want attention" is trivializing the debates about language in the US (and elsewhere) a bit too much. What language to use for what concepts is a topic which is quite important to a lot of people. And none of the examples at the end of the answer are really relevant because neither is about language.

Comment: @Philipp, The kind of journalists who inspire questions like this don't merely *want* attention, they **need** it or starve, but they're not starving, so...    We might agree that people feel important about which sports franchise they most identify with, but passion about trivia can't make it important in any general political sense.  The language debates covered by the mass media of 10, 20, and 40 are as perishable as sports scores and diet fads.  *(cont.)*

Comment: @Philipp, *(cont.)*  This is not to suggest that debates about language usage are never important, they can be, but such debates differ, (in that they're often well focused, resolvable, and useful), from the sort of intractable partisan language squabbles that most interest a mass audience with a short attention span.