# Is political correctedness meant to reduce offence or to let people perceive a rosier reality?

Tags: society

[This question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/44142/is-political-correctness-applied-to-science-terms-something-usual-in-the-us) reminded me the controversy about the usage of the "Master/Slave" terminology. According to an answer posted to the question that terminology is being replaced by less controversial terms. But I wondered if the purpose was to reduce offence or let people forget that currently in many working environments a kind of Master/Slave relationship still exists.

I then started to think about other cases and eventually I wondered it the result of applying politically correct terminology was to actually let people perceive a false reality, rosier than the actual one. Am I correct? If yes, can it be an unwanted consequence or is it done on purpose?

Comment: This I think will end up as hopelessly opinion based.  Whatever neutral meaning "politically correct" may once have had, it is now merely a phrase used as a term of attack.  That is almost nobody would say that they are want politically correct language, it is always an accusation thrown at them by others. It's pretty clear that in the "master/slave" the reference to "slave" can be seen as trivialising the consequences of chattel slavery in the Americas.

Comment: Voting to reopen - the impact of language on the human mind and politics is well studied, and so its application in politics can be explained factually.

Comment: I think the idea of *political correctness* was to make people more aware of how similarly commonplace/innocuous language might be actually perceived as offensive by people of different background. In practice the concept is often abused - either by taking on extreme or by applying it only to "fashionable" subjects. In the US and Europe one can say lots of stuff that Russians, Israelis or Arabs consider offensive, and no one would object (or, if they do, they would be accused of supporting Putin, defending occupation or being Islamist.)

Comment: I think that the main problem here is that all the users who posted or commented assumed that all the instances of politically correct language are similar and stem from the same causes. They also assume that the intentions of those who raised an issue and those who eventually decided the definition to adopt are the same. Their final conclusion is that all of them must be well meaning. On the other hand I think that the world is a lot more complex and not always well meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, political correctness is meant to reduce offence, and to increase one's understanding of another culture. No, it is not meant to whitewash the past, as political correctness implies you understand why saying something not politically correct is wrong.

It is connected to the political philosophy of multiculturalism. The idea behind it is to communicate effectively without offending the other party, especially if they are minorities or a marginalised group that has faced political suppression or violence.

For example, in the west *Negro* became a denigrating and derogatory slang for non-white people who were formerly slaves, mainly from Africa. It was replaced by the word "*black*". But since it still had negative connotations, it was replaced yet again by the term "*African American*". A more extreme example to force people to recognize the need to eschew hurtful terms and enforce political correctness can be found in India. In India, lower-caste community names among the Hindus are often used in a similar derogatory fashion as insults, mostly by the more powerful upper-caste community in India. The people of these community were often referred to as "*untouchables*". Gandhi tried to change peoples attitude by encouraging the use of the word "*Harijan*", instead, which meant *Children of the God Hari Vishnu* but this measure was not really successful in changing people's attitude. Subsequently, more drastic political measures had to be introduced to change people's attitude - using castiest words as slurs against these marginalised Indians is now a crime in India.

Simply put, in a multi-cultural society, all of us need to put in some effort to understand each others culture or we may end up hurting someone. At best, some people might not be offended. But sometimes, lack of understanding and respect can lead to political violence.

Language has a powerful impact on our minds, and how we think. How we think shapes our attitude and governs our actions. (It's a well studied field and I'll expand briefly on this, and add references, when I have some more time. Noam Chomsky's books are a good read for this topic).

Answer (score 1):

**Neither one. It actually *changes* reality.**

How we talk reflects how we think. And vice versa. Some scientists talk about [linguistic relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity), or the Sapir-Whorf-hypothesis. There is some controversy how strong the effect is, but there can be no doubt that an ingrained habit of "politically correct" speech will also affect people's actions to some degree. By making ourselves aware of how we speak, we question how we act, and this questioning may change how we act. And then the next generation grows up, not even thinking the bias any more except in history books, the dark ages when life was nasty, brutish, and short.

The effect is somewhat countered when freshly adopted euphemisms [become taboo words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism#Lifespan) themselves, which could be interpreted as the old stigma remaining, even if the labels change. Being forced to mouth phrases one does not believe might even breed resentment.